# How to correct the clearInterval when setInterval given to global variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Here is my code

**HTML Code**

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```

The following is piece of **Javascript** code

```
//The below line is outside of document ready
var interval;

//The below code is wraped in  document ready
$("input").live("click", function(){

 var length = $('li').length, start = 1;
    alert(length+' : '+start);
    interval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (length > 0 && start <= length) {
                        alert('IF section');
                        $('li:nth-child('+start+')').
                           removeClass('hidden').addClass('visible');
                        start++;
                    } else {
                        alert('Else section with before clearInterval called');
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        alert('Else section with after clearInterval called');

                    }
}, 3000);


});
```

Here `ELSE` section is called repeately after `clearInterval` method is executed. One interesting thing is **alert**  before `clearInterval` statement is repeately  called, while **alert** after `clearInterval` is not called in `setInterval` method. You can find an example of this in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QZxtL/). In Fiddle `var interval` is inside the DomReady. It should be outside of DomReady. I don't know how to put it outside of DomReady in fiddle.

Why this happens?

How to correct this?

Comment: Shouldn't the argument to your `clearInterval` call be `interval` rather than `showBlock`

Comment: or "this", cuz you are defining interval

Comment: Reading from the console: "Uncaught Reference Error: showBlock is not defined (repeated 24 times)". Reading from clearInterval docs, "The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for the clearInterval() method." - It looks like you're trying to use an uninitialized variable as the identifier for the timer you'd like to kill. I guess the code just ceases at that point, waiting to be re-triggered in another 3 seconds. To fix, replace the word 'showBlock' with the var 'interval' in your above snippet. :)

Comment: Sorry to all, it's just an typo.

Answer (score 1):

Check this **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/QZxtL/1/

All you need to do is change your `clearInterval` call to `clearInterval(interval);`

*Note*: I changed the interval to 1000 ms to make testing easier. :-)

Comment: Sorry, it's just an typo. One thing, I want to say is `var Interval` is declared outside the DOMReady.